# Android Studio SD Card erroneously reports being empty to my app

Tags: android

After going through the headache of figuring out how to make a large SD card (~32gb) using mksdcard and pushing information to it (slowly) using ADB, I can go on to my AVD manager, start up my Nexus 4 (with all default settings), and go to

Settings > Device > Storage & USB > Portable Storage > SDCARD

I see all of the files I expect to see there (i.e. all the default stuff plus everything I pushed).

However, in my app, it tells me there's nothing there. I have a menu item that calls this simple function, but its results are baffling.

```
public void dumpSDCardContents(MenuItem m) {
    if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
        recursFiles(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
    }
}

private void recursFiles(File dir){
    System.out.println("Now scanning " + dir.getAbsolutePath());
    File[] listFiles = dir.listFiles();
    if(listFiles != null){
        for(File file : listFiles){
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
            if(file.isDirectory()){
                recursFiles(file);
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("That directory has nothing in it.");
    }
}
```

All I see in logcat is

```
Now scanning /storage/19E8-1D10
That directory has nothing in it.
```

Which is bollocks. If I go to the File Explorer tab in DDMS, I can see the web of linking from `/mnt/sdcard/` to `/sdcard/` to `/storage/self/primary/` to `/mnt/user/0/primary/` to (finally) `/storage/19E8-1D10/` and then looking in that directory, plain as day, is all the data I'm looking for.

I was sure to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to my AndroidManifest.xml, and besides,  the javadoc comment on `Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED` (which I already successfully tested against) says "Storage state if the media is present and mounted at its mount point with read/write access."

What am I missing here???

-

**UPDATE:**

So I changed the `recursFiles` function to dump file permissions

```
private void recursFiles(File dir){
    System.out.println("Now scanning " + dir.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("Can r dir? " + dir.canRead());
    System.out.println("Can w dir? " + dir.canWrite());
    System.out.println("Can x dir? " + dir.canExecute());
    File[] listFiles = dir.listFiles();
    if(listFiles != null){
        for(File file : listFiles){
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
            if(file.isDirectory()){
                recursFiles(file);
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("That directory has nothing in it.");
    }
}
```

and (not terribly surprisingly given the original output) it tells me

```
Now scanning /storage/17F2-2913
Can r dir? false
Can w dir? false
Can x dir? true
That directory has nothing in it.
```

So. Why would the `Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)` check come back true (implying I have both read and write) when I in fact have neither read nor write permissions??

And how do I fix this?

I noticed when I went into the emulator using `adb shell`, that permissions files (i.e. `/system/etc/permissions/platform.xml` and `/etc/permissions/platform.xml`) flat out don't even have a permission tag for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

How do I rectify all this??

Comment: Try saving a file with the Android APIs.  Likely they are only going to give you access to a special subdirectory on the the card.